# Where do malloc() and free() store allocated sizes and addresses?

Tags: c, memory, heap-memory, free

Where do `malloc()` and `free()` store the allocated addresses and their sizes (Linux GCC)? I've read that some implementations store them somewhere before the actual allocated memory, but I could not confirm that in my tests.

The background, maybe someone has another tip for this:

I'm experimenting a little bit with analyzing the heap memory of a process in order to determine the current value of a string in the other process.
Accessing the process heap memory and strolling through it is no problem. However, because the value of the string changes and the process allocates a new part of the memory each time, the string's address changes. Because the string has a fixed format it's still easy to find, but after a few changes the old versions of the string are still in the heap memory (probably freed, but still not reused / overwritten) and thus I'm not able to tell which string is the current one.

So, in order to still find the current one I want to check if a string I find in the memory is still used by comparing its address against the addresses `malloc()` and `free()` know about.

ciao,
Elmar

Comment: Further to my answer below, this might help a bit http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/linux-programming-scripting/52375-reading-memory-other-processes.html

Comment: You might also want to dig around in the memory mapping portion of the kernel/glibc

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are lots of ways in which malloc/free can store the size of the memory area. For example, it might be stored just before the area returned by malloc. Or it might be stored in a lookup table elsewhere. Or it might be stored implicitly: some areas might be reserved for specific sizes of allocations.

To find out how the C library in Linux (glibc) does this, get the source code from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/ and look at the `malloc/malloc.c` file. There is some documentation at the top, and it refers to [A Memory Allocator](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html) by Doug Lea.

Comment: Nice and succinct, I've got a hard time following Aiden's odd answer, I dont really think he answered it anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

This is up to the implementation of the standard library, of course. So your best bet would probably be to dig through the source of the library ([glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) is the default on Linux) and see if you can figure it out. It is probably not going to be trivial.