# How to track malloc and free?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simple C implementation to track memory malloc/free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852072/simple-c-implementation-to-track-memory-malloc-free)

I need to know how much memory I have used till now in a C program and here is the pseudo code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int usedMemory =0;

void *MyMalloc(int size){
 usedMemory = usedMemory +size ;
 return malloc(size);
}

void MyFree(void *pointer){
/*****************what should i write here????*************/
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *temp1= (char *)MyMalloc(100);
    char *temp2= (char *)MyMalloc(100);

    /*......other operations.........*/

    MyFree(temp1);
    MyFree(temp2);

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what to write in the MyFree method(which decrements the amount of memory freed from usedMemory.

Comment: I ask why you want to accomplish this? Is it more of a self test for yourself or are you trying to analyze data usage? If you're just trying to track and understand memory usage take a look at the `valgrind` application that is freely available.

Comment: What if `malloc` fails? Try `void *MyMalloc(int size) { void *tmp = malloc(size); if (tmp) usedMemory += size; return tmp; }` instead :)

Comment: Removed `C++` tag, as the question is specially about `C`.

Comment: @Nawaz: Not necessarily; the OP casts the void pointer, indicating that this is C++.

Comment: @Kerrek: or the OP has a bug (missing `<stdlib.h>` and consequently improper use of `malloc`) and used the cast to shut the compiler up (and keep the bug). If it were C++ the included header would have been `<iostrem>` or `<cstdio>` or some other thing with no trailing `.h` :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could allocate few *extra* bytes more than asked, and store the size in the extra bytes, so that you could know the size later on, in `MyFree` function, with little calculation as:

```
unsigned long int usedMemory = 0;

void *MyMalloc(int size)
{
  char *buffer = (char *) malloc(size + sizeof(int)); //allocate sizeof(int) extra bytes 
  if ( buffer == NULL) 
      return NULL; // no memory! 

  usedMemory += size ;      
  int *sizeBox = (int*)buffer;
  *sizeBox = size; //store the size in first sizeof(int) bytes!
  return buffer + sizeof(int); //return buffer after sizeof(int) bytes!
}

void MyFree(void *pointer)
{
   if (pointer == NULL)
       return; //no free

   char *buffer = (char*)pointer - sizeof(int); //get the start of the buffer
   int *sizeBox = (int*)buffer;
   usedMemory -= *sizeBox;
   free(buffer);
}
```

Comment: Be aware that if `malloc` returns blocks with greater alignment than `sizeof(int)` then this returns unaligned memory, and that `int` is permitted to be smaller than `size_t` anyway. For a quick hack on a particular platform, just use whatever integer type seems reasonable with that in mind, which of course might well be `int`.

Comment: As Steve says -- best to figure out the maximum alignment, allocate *that* much more and then write the int at the beginning of that extra piece.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Honestly, I don't know much about alignment, so can't make it any better in that regard (I'm not confident). Feel free to edit this answer, or post a new answer so I can learn alignment issues as well.

Comment: It's difficult to portably detect alignment requirements. In C++11 and C1X, you should move the pointer on by the greater of `sizeof(int)` and `alignof(max_align_t)` in order to make space for an `int` without dis-aligning the allocation. In C99 you can play fairly safe with something like `sizeof(union { long double a; intmax_t b; void *c; })`, but that will probably waste space.

Comment: isn't it possible to allocate a struct{ int a; void* b} and the compare the adresses of a and b? the difference should give you the exact distance between those possibly alligned blocks, shouldn't it? (assuming this difference is the same every time...)

Comment: @xmoex: good point, if you do `struct GetAlignment {char c; T t;};`, then `offsetof(struct GetAlignment, t)` is guaranteed to be a multiple of the alignment requirement of the type `T`. And in practice will be equal to it unless the implementation adds pointless excess padding to the structure. So if you throw everything that you think might have a large alignment requirement into a union, call that `T`, then you get the worst alignment requirement, *provided the implementation doesn't define any additional types that you don't know about it*.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, you could keep a global `std::map<void*, std::size_t>` around to track the size of each allocated block; your own allocator function would register the size when allocating, and the deallocation function would remove the entry. (Update: Or do as the linked question suggests and allocate a bit more memory and save the size there.)

The more fundamental problem is that this will probably only be of very limited use in a typical C++ program: Allocations there are done predominantly in two ways: 1) through explicit `new` expressions, which call `::operator new()`, which in turn (usually) calls `malloc()`, and 2) through `std::allocator<T>::allocate()`, which on many platforms is implemented in terms of `::operator new()`.

The problem is that you don't have control over the specifics of your platform. You can replace the global operator-new to use your own `MyMalloc()`, but the default `std::allocator` might use `malloc()` directly and thus not be affected by that.

A cleaner approach for debugging purposes is to use an external tool like `valgrind` to track heap usage. For permanent internal use, tracking the allocation sizes is going to cause a significant performance hit, too.

Answer (score 2):

You could allocate memory and store its size in the allocated block (error checking omitted for brevity):

```
unsigned int totalAlloc = 0;

void *MyAlloc(unsigned int size)
{
    void *p;
    totalAlloc += size;

    p = malloc(size + sizeof(int));
    *(int *) p = size;
    return (void *)(((int *) p) + 1)
}

void MyFree(void *ptr)
{
    ptr = (void *)(((int *) ptr) -1 );
    totalAlloc -= * (int *) ptr;
    free(ptr);
}
```

This code actually reserves more memory than requested in order to store the block's size in the (usually) first four bytes. This information can then be retrieved later on when you free the memory.

Comment: The problem is that you no longer return a well-aligned pointer, which in principle causes undefined behaviour all over the map.

Comment: That I don't get. Shouldn't this in principle be an allocation of "just 4 bytes more"? If I chose to allocate an array of `char` and - by principle - begin writing data to that array at index 5, the memory is still properly allocated, isn't it?

Comment: It's allocated, but not aligned right.

Comment: @Linus: suppose your C implementation requires 8-alignment for some builtin type T (this is rare, but permitted by the standard -- T might be `long long`, or `double`). Then `malloc` will return an address that is 8-aligned. You add 4 to the pointer, so the address you return is not 8-aligned. Therefore if a caller does `T *buf = MyAlloc(sizeof(T)); if (buf) {*buf = 0;}` they get undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage a list of all malloc() you have done with pointer + size. Then you can search for the size in that list, and decrement it in free().

Check for example in that example how they are doing:
http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/lib_interposers_code.html#malloc_interposer.c

You might have other possibilities to track memory, like:

- [Valgrind with massif tool](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html) for tracking memory usage over time. You can even generate [png output graphics](http://wingolog.org/archives/2008/05/05/catching-memory-leaks-with-valgrinds-massif)
- Interposed libraries. You can found some libraries that you can use by `LD_PRELOAD=thelib.so ./yourprogram`, and they will output some statistics like [jemalloc](http://www.canonware.com/jemalloc/)

(A side note, please accept some answers to your question !)

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this... i'd strongly recommend to use this only for debugging purpose!

```
#define MAXMEMBLOCKS 10000

typedef struct {
    int size;
    void* ptr;
} memblock;

typedef struct {
    int totalSize;
    int current;
    memblock memblocks[MAXMEMBLOCKS];
} currentMemory;

currentMemory mem;

void *MyMalloc(int size) {
    if (mem.current < MAXMEMBLOCKS) {
        mem.current += size;
        mem.memblocks[mem.current].size = size;
        mem.memblocks[mem.current].ptr = malloc(size);
        return mem.memblocks[mem.current++].ptr;
    } else {
        // you needed more memblocks than estimated
        return NULL;
    }
};

int MyFree(void *pointer) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < mem.current; i++) {
        if (mem.memblocks[i].ptr == pointer) {
            mem.totalSize -= mem.memblocks[i].size;
            free(mem.memblocks[i].ptr);
            mem.current--;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    // you tried to free a block wich hasn't been allocated through MyMalloc()
    return -1;
}
```