# How to "return" an array from a function to main in c

Tags: c, arrays, function, program-entry-point

I want to pass an arrays index from my function to main. How can I do that?
For example:

```
void randomfunction()
{
    int i;
    char k[20][10];
    for (i=0;i<20;i++)
        strcpy(k[i], "BA");
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i; for (i=0;i<20;i++) printf("%s",k[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

I know that for you this is very simple but I've found similar topics and they were too complicated for me. I just want to pass the k array to main. Of course my purpose is not to fill it with "BA" strings...

Comment: Firstly, your code won't compile, is that code meant to be part of `randomfunction`?  Second, what do you mean by "pass the k array to main`? Show an example of how `randomfunction` is called and `k` is used in `main`.

Comment: @etheranger what about now?

Comment: Better. It's still not entirely clear (but we can guess) when `randomfunction` is called. Normally "passing a value from `a` to `b`" means that `a` calls `b`.  It would of course be a nonsensical thing for `randomfunction` to call `main`, but given the naivety of the question you could have been trying to do that, and would need a different answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to allocate the memory dynamically. Like this:

```
char** randomfunction() {    
    char **k=malloc(sizeof(char*)*20);
    int i;

    for (i=0;i<20;i++)
        k[i]=malloc(sizeof(char)*10);

    //populate the array

    return k;    
}

int main() {
    char** arr;
    int i;

    arr=randomfunction();

    //do you job

    //now de-allocate the array
    for (i=0;i<20;i++)
        free(arr[i]);        
    free(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

See about [`malloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) and [`free`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/).

Comment: what is free(arr) doing?

Comment: @GeorgeDavidKing It returns the memory you allocated with `malloc()` to the system.

Comment: @GeorgeDavidKing `malloc` allocates memory in the heap and `free` releases that memory.

Comment: @GeorgeDavidKing The `k` array is returned into the `arr` array. `arr` points to the same location as `k` pointed to. So `free`ing `arr` frees the space allocated for `k`. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957099/how-do-free-and-malloc-work-in-c

Comment: @GeorgeDavidKing It seems that your basics about pointers are not clear. You can try a good book and read it. It will help you in the long run.

Comment: @Rikayan Bandyopadhyay can you please suggest me one?

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option. This works because `struct`s can be copied around , unlike arrays.

```
typedef struct 
{
    char arr[20][10];
} MyArray;

MyArray random_function(void)
{
    MyArray k;
    for (i=0;i<sizeof k.arr / sizeof k.arr[0];i++)
       strcpy(k.arr[i], "BA");
    return k;
}

int main()
{
     MyArray k = random_function();
}
```

Comment: I like this option. +1. But it maybe unnecessary to create structs every time you want to return an array.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way:

```
void randomfunction(char k[][10])
{
    // do stuff
}

int main()
{
    char arr[20][10];
    randomfunction(arr);
}
```

If `randomfunction` needs to know the dimension `20`, you can pass it as another argument. (It doesn't work to put it in the `[]` , for historial reasons).

Comment: Read the question. There is a word in quotes.

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay output parameters are a perfectly good way to "return" values.

Comment: @etheranger You still don't get it. The question says `"return" an array`.

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay You still don't get it. You can (and often should) return data through pointer parameters. Yes, it's not syntactically the same as a literal `return` statement, but that's not what this question is about.