# C: allocate a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

So we have a struct that is actually representing a node of a linked list. Also a pointer that points to node.

```
typedef struct node{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
}node;

node* head=NULL;
```

If I am going to dynamically allocate the pointer using malloc,

```
head=malloc(sizeof(node));
```

that means that I am creating some memory space, with size of node, and head is pointing at it.

I would like to know the difference between this  `head=malloc(sizeof(node*));`, as you can see in the sizeof it has node* instead of node. Now I really think that all this time I had no idea what  malloc really does!

Comment: `malloc` will give you a pointer to some memory at least as big as the size that you ask for (although sometimes it will return `NULL`, on failure). Did you try actually printing out `sizeof(node)` versus `sizeof(node *)` to see what you get?

Comment: You do not "allocate a pointer", but an object of the type it **points to** and assign the address to the pointer. Now think which size you have to pass to `malloc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
head=malloc(sizeof(node*));
```

Will allocate a space in memory to hold a POINTER to a object of type node.

```
head=malloc(sizeof(node));
```

Will allocate space for the structure itself, and return to you the address of that memory space, and you will hold that in the `head` variable

For more info, check this other question about Malloc.
[How do free and malloc work in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957099/how-do-free-and-malloc-work-in-c)

Comment: So what's the point to type that "head=malloc(sizeof(node*));" anyway?

Comment: @Skemelio If you wanted to allocate a pointer, for some reason. You might write `node **head = malloc(sizeof(node*));`

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(node)` is the size in bytes of the whole struct, which can be arbitrarily large. `sizeof(node*)` is the size of a pointer variable, which is fixed, no matter how large is the structure (and it is pretty small on most systems).

Answer (score 1):

```
head=malloc(sizeof(node*));
```

is incorrect. That call to `malloc` allocates enough memory to hold only a `node*`. A `node*` must point to a `node` object. That means you need to allocate sufficient memory to hold a `node` object, not a `node*`.