# Deleting resources

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm a beginner in C. I currently have a task to create a program having multiple queues. How should i correct this? From my understanding, is supposed to clear all of the queues that where created. As currently i think i have memory leaks.

```
#include <stdio.h> //printf etc
#include <stdlib.h> //malloc calloc realloc free
#include <stdint.h>

/* number of message queues */
#define MSGQS_LEN 5

/* number of nodes in the message queue */
#define CAPACITY 5

typedef struct _node {
    const char* message;
    struct _node* next;
} node_t;

typedef struct {
    char qName;
    node_t *front, *rear;
} msg_queue_t;


typedef struct {
    msg_queue_t **queues;
} MsgQs_t;
```

Comment: This thread might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957099/how-do-free-and-malloc-work-in-c. Basically you should `free` the memory you allocate with `malloc` (and variants).

Comment: *"As currently i think i have memory leaks."* - Why?

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several problems.

```
if(msg_queues < 0)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

This test is not correct, msg_queues will be NULL if malloc failed for some reason, the test should read.

```
if(msg_queues == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

```
/* Relinquishes all resources currently held by a MsgQs_t.
   The pointer to the MsgQs_t in question is set to NULL. */
MsgQs_t* unloadMsgQs(){
    MsgQs_t *msg_queues;
    msg_queues = NULL;

    return(msg_queues);
}
```

You allocate a variable on the stack, initialize it to NULL and return NULL from this function.

What you actually want to do is pass a MsqQs_t* to `unloadMsgQs` and use this pointer as an argument to `free`, something like this

```
void unloadMsgQs(MsgQs_t *msg_q) {
    if(msg_q) {
        free(msg_q);
    }
}
```

If you want to set the msg_q pointer to NULL so that it can't be reused anymore, you should probably do something like.

```
void unloadMsgQs(MsgQs_t **msg_q) {
    if(msg_q && *msg_q) {
        free(*msg_q);
        *msg_q = NULL;
    }
}
```

From what I see, my advice would be to read some more books / tutorials on programming with C and pointers in general, because it seems you don't quite grasp the basics yet (which is nothing to be ashamed of of course!)

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `free` with the pointer value returned from `malloc`. For this you have to pass the pointer to `unloadMsgQs` as an argument.

If this function is supposed to set the pointer to `NULL` in the caller, you have to pass the address of the pointer.

Note that `malloc`'s return value to indicate an error is `NULL` not a value `< 0`.

```
/* Returns a pointer to MsgQs_t structure and through which multiple message queues can be subsequently created.
   Each individual message queue is to be identified by a unique identifier. */
MsgQs_t* initializeMsgQs(){
    MsgQs_t* msg_queues;
    msg_queues = malloc(sizeof(MsgQs_t));

    if(msg_queues == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    return(msg_queues);
}


/* Relinquishes all resources currently held by a MsgQs_t.
   The pointer to the MsgQs_t in question is set to NULL. */
void unloadMsgQs(MsgQs_t **msg_queues){

    if(msg_queues != NULL)
    {
        free(*msg_queues);
        *msg_queues = NULL;
    }
}

/* sample use in main() */
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MsgQs_t* msg_queues;

    msg_queues = initializeMsgQs();
    /* ... */
    unloadMsgQs(&msg_queues);

    return 0;
}
```