# How does free() know how much memory to free?

Tags: c, memory-management, free

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C programming : How does free know how much to free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518711/c-programming-how-does-free-know-how-much-to-free)

In this snippet

```
void main() {
void *p = malloc(300);
printf("%d",sizeof(*p));
free(p);
}
```

How does free know much memory it is supposed release from the void pointer?

I figure, if there is an internal table/function, it should be available to find out sizes of any kind of objects, whereas the output of the `printf` is `1`

Comment: my bad, i should really have searched without the parenthesis :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

malloc and free do their own hidden accounting so they can do the correct thing.

The reason the sizeof() does not use this accounting information is that sizeof() is a compile time operator, and the malloc/free information is not available until runtime.

Answer (score 3):

see [comp.lang.c FAQ list · Question 7.26](http://c-faq.com/malloc/freesize.html)

Comment: Please include actual information in answers, in addition to links that may become stale.

Comment: Why was this voted down? It's exactly right.

Comment: It's _highly_ unlikely the comp.lang.c FAQ is going to become stale before Stack Overflow does...

Comment: The comp.lang.c FAQ might move, and the section referenced only answers half of the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is implementation dependant. In some systems I've seen, it reserves some bytes *before* the pointer with information of the size of the reserved chunk, next free slot of memory, etc.  As for the `sizeof(void)`, this is not specified.

Answer (score 0):

Each implementation of `malloc` has an internal data structure of how many blocks it allocated.  `free` and `malloc` go hand-in-hand so free knows exactly where to look.

See [this Wiki article on Free List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_list) for more information

Comment: "... of how many blocks it allocated", of the location of each block allocated, and of the size of each block allocated: so for any block that's being freed, it (the 'heap implementation') remembers how big that block was.

Comment: this article should really be on wiki's malloc & free articles