# Dynamic Memory Allocation for Arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory, dynamic, malloc

So I'm trying to create a dynamic array in C, using malloc, but for some reason it's not working out. Here's my code:

```
    int* test = (int*) malloc(20 * sizeof(int));
    printf("Size: %d\n", sizeof(test));
```

The console outputs 8 when I run this code, although it ideally should output 80, I believe, since the size of an int is 4, and I'm creating 20 of them. So why isn't this working? Thanks for any help. :)

Comment: remember to check the return value of malloc always, check the documentation for that....

Comment: Sidenote: when programming in C please do not cast the return value of `malloc`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `sizeof` operator is returning the size of an `int*`, which is just a pointer.  In C, when you allocate memory dynamically using `malloc`, the call to `malloc` returns a pointer to the newly allocated block of memory (usually on the heap.)  The pointer itself is just a memory address (which usually only takes up 4 or 8 bytes on most modern systems).  You'll need to keep track of the actual number of bytes allocated yourself.

The C language will only keep track of buffer sizes for statically allocated buffers (stack arrays) because the size of the array is available at compile time.

```
int test[100];
printf("Sizeof %d\n", sizeof(test))
```

This will print a value equal to `100 * sizeof(int)` (usually 400 on most modern machines)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So how can I get the size of a dynamic array?

Comment: @Mr Cherno, you can't get it using standard ANSI-C.  You have to simply keep track of it yourself using a separate variable.  (You know you allocated a buffer equal to the size of `20 * sizeof(int)`).

Comment: @CharlesSalvia, one pedantic point, the size of dynamically allocated memory is kept track of otherwise you would have to specify the size when you call free() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518711/c-programming-how-does-free-know-how-much-to-free

Answer (score 3):

Here `sizeof` operator is giving you the number of bytes required to store an `int*`
i.e. it is equivalent to `sizeof(int*);`
Depending on the compiler it may give you `4` or `8`

**In C its programmers job to keep track of number of bytes allocated dynamically.**

Answer (score 0):

if you try to print value of sizeof (&test), you will get 80 (20 * 4). &test is of type int (*) [20].

I hope it clarifies your doubt.