# Pointer dynamic memory allocation?

Tags: c

If we dynamically allocated memory for a pointer in c

```
ptr=(cast-type*)malloc(byte-size)
```

and

```
free(ptr);
```

when we free that pointer how the free command know about how much byte size is allocated for that pointer in c. Is that data is stored in any of the memory ????

Comment: It will depend on the implementation.

Comment: One way or another, the function that allocates the memory (e.g., `malloc`) retains enough information behind the curtain to enable it to free that memory, given just the address it previously returned.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518711/how-does-free-know-how-much-to-free

Comment: "We" do not cast the result of `malloc` in C.