# Can I not set null termination on a char array?

Tags: c

I am trying to make a small function to get a string between two tags. But I get a segfault on `str[len -3] = '\0';`

Is it not possible to add a null-termination to the string passed and then send a pointer back?

Is it bad practice to change the index of the pointer instead of copying it over to a buffer and send it back?

Do I get a memory leak from the 3 bytes never getting freed?

```
/*
    format for a message
    <m>Hello world!</>13594750394883323106
    <m>"msg"</><checksum>
*/
//returns the string beetween tags
char *GetMessage(char *str) {
    int len = strlen(str);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (str[i] == '<' && str[i + 1] == 'm' && str[i + 2] == '>') {
            if (str[len - 3] == '<' && str[len - 2] == '/' && str[len - 1] == '>') {
                str[len - 3] = '\0';
                return &str[3];
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: `return &str[3];` -> `return str + 3;`

Comment: Without seeing the code that frees the memory allocated to the string, we can only guess. Is there some software telling you that there is a memory leak? If so, can you show us the message?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Assume free() on the returned pointer.

Comment: Doesn't this line (`if(str[i] == '<' && str[i+1] == 'm' && str[i+2] == '>')`) create problems when you're testing the last two characters of the string? For example, when` i == len - 1` (last character of the string), you'll be reference to characters that are beyond the end of the string if it's == `<'

Comment: Yes @TravisGriggs that might be a problem if the string is corrupt. I am not sure how I will handle that

Comment: In the first paragraph, I think you mean `str[len - 3] = '\0';` rather than `str[str -3] = '\0';`.

Comment: Are you trying to free the memory returned by `&str[3]`?

Comment: If `str` points to a `malloc`-allocated chunk of memory, then `free(&str[3])` has undefined behavior; you can only `free()` a pointer value that was returned by `malloc` or equivalent (or a null pointer).

Comment: @Amadeus Yes later I will try to free that memory.

I have a buffer for an incoming string, that buffer will be sent to this function. The returned value will be evaluated but not modification. 

I will then free that buffer

Comment: Why does it return `str + 3`?. Shouldn't it return `str + i + 3`?

Comment: How do you handle the string containing multiple messages?

Comment: It would be useful to see how this function is called.

Comment: If you're going to free the sub fragment and/or the original independent from each other, then you should use strdup() or similar to get a second copy of the substring, so you can free them independently

Comment: @Jacob to prevent the problems described by Travis Griggs, you need to stop the loop when [i+2] == [len-3]. To explain the segfault, the input str is maybe considered as const.

Comment: Can you give us enough code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Chances are you're passing a string literal to this function and you can't modify string literals reliably — it often crashes (though the behaviour is undefined and worse things than crashes can happen).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Aha. I did not know that. I am just calling this function with a GetMessage("<m>Hello world!</>"); string when i got the problem. But that explains it

Comment: @TravisGriggs  this line `if(str[i] == '<' && str[i+1] == 'm' && str[i+2] == '>'` works fine because if `i` is `len-1`, `str[i+1]` is `\0` (i.e. is not `m`) and `str[i+2]` is not evaluated thanks to the short circuit nature of `&&`. Stopping earlier as @J. Piquard suggested is a good option, though.

Comment: @Mad Physicist: `return &str[3];` is the same as `return str + 3;` with the former version being *preferable* in many cases.

Comment: @Mad Physicist: `if(str[i] == '<' && str[i+1] == 'm' && str[i+2] == '>')` is **not** equivalent to `strcmp(str + i, "<m>") == 0`. It can be replaced with `strncmp`, but not with what you suggested.

Comment: @AnT. Good call. Should be `strncmp(str + i, "<m>", 3)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resume answers for the questions.

1)
Is it not possible to add a nulltermination to the string passed and then send a pointer back?

It turned out that the string passed as a literal was the problem in this case. [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) pointed this out in the comments and that was exactly how I tested the function.

```
GetMessage("<m>Hello world!</>");
```

When tested in conjunction with other functions answering without literals it worked well.

```
GetMessage(ReadSerialData());
```

2)
Is it bad practice to change the index of the pointer instead of copying it over to a buffer and send it back?

This appears to be of preference. But should not caus any problems.

3)
I get a memory leak from the 3 bytes never getting freed?

This was really good explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518711/how-does-free-know-how-much-to-free)

---

Thanks for all the inputs!

Answer (score 3):

To better reasoning about this, let's to draw the memory layout of your string. If I got it correctly it is something like:

```
                     111111
           0123456789012345...
        -> xxxxx<m>Hi</>yyy...\0
```

Now you want to pass a pointer to the first character of your string to `GetMessage()` and print the first message. Something like

```
fullmsg ="....";
m = fullmsg;
m = GetMessage(m);
printf("msg: %s\n",m);
... // Advance m
```

Of course you can't do `fullmsg=GetMessage(fullmsg)` or weird things may happen (memory leak being the least :) ).

When you've found the `<m>` tag your situation is:

```
                     111111
           0123456789012345...
    str -> xxxxx<m>Hi</>yyy...\0
                ^             ^
                i             len
```

Which shows that returning `str+3` does not do what you want. Your return value should be `str+i+3`.

In the same vein, it's not `str[len-3]` that you should put to `\0`. Just imagine the effect on: `GetMessage("x<m>aa</>yzyy")`. The character in position `len-3` is `z`. Not what you wanted, I guess.

What you could do is to use another index to find the end of the message:

```
      for (j = i+1; j<len-2; j++) {
        if (str[j] == '<' && str[j+1] == '/' && str[j+2] == '>') {
           // end of message found!!!!
        }
      }
```

So that when you have found the end of the message your situation is:

```
                     111111
           0123456789012345...
    str -> xxxxx<m>Hi</>yyy...\0
                ^    ^        ^
                i    j        len
```

I wish I could tell you that you could simply do `str[j]='\0'`  and return `str+i+3 but, unfortunately I can't. If you do it and pass a literal string (`m=GetMessage("Hi there!")` you will get a coredump as the memory used for a string between quotes is read-only.

A possible solution is to change the semantic of your `GetMessage()` a little bit:

```
    // returns the length of the message if the string starts with <m>
    int GetMessage(char *str) {
       int len = 0;
       if (str[0]=='<' && str[1]=='m' && str[2]=='>') {
         str += 3;
         while (str[0] != '\0') {
            if (str[0]=='<' && str[1]=='/' && str[2] == '>')
              return len;
            str++;
         }
       }
       return 0;
    }
```

Now, when you want to print the message you can do something like:

```
    fullmessage = "xxxx<m>Hi</>yyyyy";
    m = fullmessage;
    l = 0;

    /* skip until you find a '<m>' tag */
    while (m[0] != '\0' && ((l=GetMessage(m)) == 0) m++;

    /* l can be 0 here if there was no message in the string */
    if (l>0) printf("msg = %.*s",l,m+3);
```

I didn't test it fully but I hope you got the idea.

Comment: Good explanation! congratulations

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a crash on `str[len-3] = '\0';` because you are trying to write to a read-only location.  String literals used as values can be placed in read-only storage, attempting to modify them invokes undefined behavior.

You cannot pass constant strings to this function.

There is a bug in your code: `return &str[3];` should be `return &str[i + 3];`.

Furthermore, your code does not handle the examples in the comments because the `</>` substring is not at the end.

Here is a simplified version:

```
#include <string.h>

char *GetMessage(char *str) {
    str = strstr(str, "<m>");
    if (str != NULL) {
        str += 3;
        char *p = strstr(str, "</>");
        if (p != NULL)
            *p = '\0';
    }
    return str;
}
```

Note that the pointer returned by `GetMessage()` points inside the argument string.  You cannot pass it to `free()` to deallocate the string, this would invoke undefined behavior. Only the original value returned by `malloc()` can be passed to `free()`.

Comment: Why did you suppose the string passed as parameter was read only?  Do you work nearby?  Are you the guy who possed the problem to @jacob ???  The parameter string is defined as `char *`, and not `const char *`, so there's nothing illegal in changing the original string, IMHO

Comment: @LuisColorado: I know this from reading Jacob's comment: *I did not know that. I am just calling this function with a GetMessage("<m>Hello world!</>"); string when i got the problem. But that explains it*. The code as written is not *illegal*, but it does make the assumption that the parameter string is modifiable, which a string literal isn't. It is a pity the compiler would not complain by default about the `const` qualification mismatch.  Invoking the compiler with increased warning level (ie `gcc -Wall -W` or equivalent) would produce a useful diagnostic message.

Comment: well, don't despair... I use to be sarchastic when I make some comment like this one.  Don't take me seriously.  I agree with you in the sentence _that it's a pity the compiler says nothing about it_.  But that's also a reminiscence of old legacy code to be compilable.